# How to get distinct values from multiple table with count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am having a situation where I need to get the records from multiple table which contains the column name `'YrId'` and I want to retrieve only distinct values from that table as well as I want to get count of values grouped by `'YrId'`. To get column which contains more than 0 values I have the following query which returns me the table name having desired column

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS [Table Name],
    'Total Record Count'=max(i.rows)
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    sysindexes i ON t.object_id=i.id
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%yrid%' 
GROUP BY 
    t.name
HAVING 
    MAX(i.rows) > 0
ORDER BY 
    [total record count] DESC
```

From this query, I get table name which has column `'yrid'` now to get distinct values I run the following query on table name which is returned by above given query.

```
select distinct yrid, 'Table1' 
from Table1
```

But I have a problem with above query that it generate output in multiple rowset which I don't want. I want to generate output in same rowset which should be like given below:

```
Table Name  YrId1Count  YrId2Count
----------------------------------
Table1       250           350
Table2       320           410
```

As far as I know it can be achieved by PIVOT but I just failed to do that.

Comment: I don't think your question is clearly understandable. Can you please rephrase the question and add some sample source data so that we know what you are actually trying to achieve? thanks.

Comment: There are many many many online examples of pivot. Did you try any?

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I assume you need number of particular column (say employeeid in my example). 
Below example will find all the table which contains column EmployeeId, It will the find Distinct EmployeeId in every table and insert in @TableCounts. At the end you have @Table Counts with table and unique number of employeeIds in each of them.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( name NVARCHAR(MAx))

DECLARE @curCol NVARCHAR(50), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @TableCounts TABLE (Name Nvarchar(max), NumberOfEmp INT)


INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 

   t.name

FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 

WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%EmployeeId%' 

    SELECT * FROM @t



    WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)>0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT Top 1 @curCol = name FROM @t

        SET @query = 'INSERT INTO @TableCounts SELECT '''+@curCol+''',COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID) FROM ' + @curCol



        EXEC sp_executesql @query;

        DELETE FROM @t where name = @curCol
    END


    SELECT * FROM @TableCounts
```

Hope That Helps !!! :)